# Java socket timeout does not apply

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I have this socket implementation in java which uses timeout:

```
        try {
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 5000);

        } catch (SocketException e2) {
            System.out.println("Something wrong with the socket: " + e2);
        }
```

The ip and port is closed, so connection cannot be made. 
But the timeout here does not work. It does not wait for 5 seconds and then return an error.

This code is located in constructor and calls from runnable class. May this be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connect timeout is the *maximum* time that `connect()` will block for. If there is an immediate connection refusal or other error, you will get it immediately. In this case the target port wasn't listening so you would have got an immediate `ConnectException: connection refused`.  It isn't obliged to wait for the timeout if the error happens sooner. The timeout is really for where there is no response at all. Waiting *after* an error doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Okay, then how could I do that it will wait for some maximum time and then return an error despite of closed port or not? May be it will be opened while waiting this timeout?

Comment: You can't. Try a loop, with sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

Socket socket = new Socket();

// This limits the time allowed to establish a connection

// timeout takes place if connection result is not received with in the specified timeout.

socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);

// This stops the request for waiting for response after connection succeeds.

socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: timeout in socket.connect means connection will timeout if it cannot connect within a certain time.

Comment: setSoTimeout specifies the time in which to disconnect if no reponse is received.

Comment: Just repeating yourself adds nothing to your answer, which still doesn't answer the question. He knows that, and he is already doing it. The question here is why he *didn't* get a timeout.

Comment: Because he is getting the connection result before 5 seconds.So the  timeout did not take place.

Comment: That's not what it says in your answer. The idea is to fix your answer, or delete it.